# How to find the Total Records of outer query

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query

```
SELECT concat(sf.from_location, "-",sf.to_location) as from_to_city,
    count( *) as seach_count,
    (SELECT count(DISTINCT fb.origin) as no_of_book 
        FROM flight_booking_details as fb 
        WHERE fb.status="BOOKING_CONFIRMED" and
             from_code=journey_from and
             to_code=journey_to AND
             DATE(fb.created_datetime) >="2018-07-01" AND
             DATE(fb.created_datetime) <="2018-07-04" AND
             fb.journey_from = 'BLR' AND
             fb.journey_to = 'DEL' ) as booking_count 
FROM search_flight_history sf 
WHERE DATE(sf.created_datetime) >= '2018-07-01' AND
     DATE(sf.created_datetime) <= '2018-07-04' AND
     (sf.from_location = 'BLR' OR
         sf.from_code = 'BLR') AND
     (sf.to_location = 'DEL' OR
         sf.to_code = 'DEL') 
GROUP BY from_code,
    to_code
```

Here I need to find the Total Records of this query.

Please any one help me to find this one

Comment: Do you need the count of rows which your query returns?

Comment: yes i need the count of rows

Answer (score 0):

If really just need the count of rows returned by your query, you can try the following:

```
select count(*)
from
(
SELECT concat(sf.from_location, "-",sf.to_location) as from_to_city,
    count( *) as seach_count,
    (SELECT count(DISTINCT fb.origin) as no_of_book 
        FROM flight_booking_details as fb 
        WHERE fb.status="BOOKING_CONFIRMED" and
             from_code=journey_from and
             to_code=journey_to AND
             DATE(fb.created_datetime) >="2018-07-01" AND
             DATE(fb.created_datetime) <="2018-07-04" AND
             fb.journey_from = 'BLR' AND
             fb.journey_to = 'DEL' ) as booking_count 
FROM search_flight_history sf 
WHERE DATE(sf.created_datetime) >= '2018-07-01' AND
     DATE(sf.created_datetime) <= '2018-07-04' AND
     (sf.from_location = 'BLR' OR
         sf.from_code = 'BLR') AND
     (sf.to_location = 'DEL' OR
         sf.to_code = 'DEL') 
GROUP BY from_code,
    to_code 
) X;
```

Comment: @AnithaG Please mark this as an answer so other users can focus on other unanswered questions.

Comment: This Query is taking time 15.6009 sec for getting the results, is there any possibility to change this query ...

Comment: @AnithaG I suggest you ask a separate question about query performance, referencing this one.